# Hide page until Knockout binding and all sub bindings are finished

Tags: knockout.js, visibility

I have page that has a knockout model, inside the knockout model there are sub models like so:

```
  function firstSubViewModel(listData) {
         var self = this;
         self.myAttribute = ko.observable();
         function that sets stuff()
         return self;
 }

var MyViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        // load the sub-viewmodels used on the page
        self.foo= new firstSubViewModel(params);
        self.bar= new secondSubViewModel(otherparams);
}
vm = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

This is just psuedocode there are really a bunch of sub models each of which has a bunch of their own attributes and other functions being called.
I would like to hide that page at first, and then when all of the of the data from all the sub models is in I will display the main page. So far I have tried setting :

```
<div id = "main" style = "display: none" data-bind = "visible: true"></div>
```

This hides the page until the main model is bound and then displays it. But if any of the submodels take a while to load they arent done when the page is displayed, such as an image based off of myAttribute in the sub model wont load if that attribute isnt filled. So a way I can fix that is.

```
<div id = "main" style = "display: none" data-bind = "visible: vm.foo.myAttribute"></div>
```

Which is saying wait until there is a value in there before showing the page, but I have a bunch of sub models with a bunch of attributes, it is a bit ridiculous to say

```
  <div data-bind = "visible:vm.foo.myAttribute && vm.bar.myAttribute && vm.bar.otherAttribute && etc.."></div>
```

Is there a cleaner way to watch and wait for all of them to be populated?

Comment: If you're already using Knockout, look into Durandal (that has Knockout as a dependency) -- its router handles lifecycle events for you. (I'm not sure if its router could be used without the rest of it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple. Have an observable on your main view model that turns `true` when all work is done.

```
<div id="main" style="display: none" data-bind="visible: allDone"></div>
```

and

```
function MainViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.foo = ko.observable();
    self.bar = new SubModel();
    // all other observables and sub-viewmodels here

    self.allDone = ko.computed(function () {
        // now just subscribe to all kinds of observables
        var foo = self.foo(),
            bar = self.bar.myAttribute();

        // ...and do value checks
        return foo > "" && bar > "";
    });
}
```

Knockout will update `allDone` as the subscribed-to properties come in, and at some point in time, the overall return value will be true.

Comment: Ahhh computed thats what I was looking for, I was just trying to tie that into an attribute and it wasnt going well.

Answer (score 2):

Although the accepted solution works, I've found an even simpler way to accomplish this (at least that worked for me).

```
<div id="content" style="display: none" data-bind="style: {display: 'block'}">
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
</div>
```

Before Knockout loads, the initial style is used, in this case display none. But as soon as Knockout finishes loading the View Model, the style within the data-bind will execute.